# Animating visibility AND opacity with wpf VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, transition, visualstatemanager

I am trying to animate a control so that it's visibility is set to visible then animating the opacity from 0 to 1

However nothing happens, then after 1 second the control is show with an opacity of 1... I cannot see what i am doing wrong

This is the code i have tried

```
<Grid x:Name="layout_root" Margin="10">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Filtering">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="filter_control" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="Filtering" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0"/>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Text}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=F2}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="v" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ShowFilterClick"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the question of what you're doing wrong or why you see the behavior that you see:  the storyboard for the Enabled state is the storyboard that the VSM uses while the VSGroup is **in** that state.  You specify a transition storyboard for the group, though, and the VSM applies that when transitioning **between** states.  So, when you put the VSGroup into the Enabled state, the VSM first plays the transition storyboard then uses the steady-state storyboard that you specify for the Enabled state.  The transition storyboard is 1 sec, and that's why you're seeing the 1 sec delay and then the pop.

Something like the following is probably what you want.  Note that the transition storyboard does the action/animation that you want, and the state storyboards just state the final values at which the animated properties should be held.  Also, I apply the easing function to the double animation rather than to the entire VisualTransition -- it doesn't make sense to try to interpolate Visibility with an easing function.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="Filtering">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition From="Disabled" To="Enabled" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1">
            <Storyboard>
               <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
               </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1">
                  <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                     <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                  </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
               </DoubleAnimation>
           </Storyboard>
       </VisualTransition>
       <!-- you could also have a transition from Enabled to Disabled -->
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <Storyboard>
               <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
               </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0"/>
           </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled">
            <Storyboard>
               <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
               </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="filter_control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
           </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Comment: I have marked you answer as accepted (because it works :-) )... But it seems that the states themselves are redundant in this case ??? I think that was what threw me off course

Comment: the states are required.  otherwise you have no way to tell the vsm what do to.  as for the storyboards in the states, the Disabled one is certainly needed so that it has visual state to go back to (otherwise, there's no statement of what that visual state is like).  have you tried it without the storyboard inside the Enabled state?

Comment: Yes, it works. In this case it seems that i could just use 2 empty states, and do all the animation in the transitions (to and from the "enabled" state)

Comment: "Note that the transition storyboard does the action/animation that you want, and the state storyboards just state the final values at which the animated properties should be held." That's precisely what I was after, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

The Visibility enum is not an inherently animatable property.  Generally only numeric properties are truly animatable, since WPF can fill in the spaces between keyframes.  For example, it knows that an opacity halfway between the value of 0 and 1 is 0.5.  It knows every possible value based on the current time.

If you animate from Visibility.Collapsed to Visibility.Visible over 1 second, it has no idea what to do at the 0.5 second mark or any other point in between.  It only knows you're changing an enum from 1 value to another.  If your transition time is 1 second, it waits till that second is up and then changes the value, so you never get to see the opacity animation happening.

You can try using FluidLayout.  You enable it like so:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="Filtering" ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.UseFluidLayout="True">
```

You can also enable it using a toggle in the Blend UI.

FluidLayout animates layout changes for you.  Collapsing or expanding an element affects the layout, so it can automatically animate those layout changes.